# Show that if $f:A\to B$ is a bijection then $f^{-1}$ is a surjection

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

The proof I have for this is as follows:

Let $a\in A$ then $f(a)=b\in B\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(b)=a$ and so for $b=f(a)\in B$ and $a=f^{-1}(b)$.

The math and everything makes sense to me but I don't understand how this shows that the function is surjective. If it is surjective then $\forall a\in A$ there exists $b\in B$ such that $a=f^{-1}(b)$ so I can kind of see why we showed that. I guess what I'm confused about is how this shows that every element in a is being mapped to.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are in bijection via $f$, then $B$ is in bijection with $A$ via $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Yea that is true but I'm not confused about that, I'm confused about why this proves the function is surjective.

Comment: A bijection is both surjective and injective by definition.

Comment: You've shown the "$\forall a \in A$" part by picking a generic $a \in A$; for any given one, you can find a $b$ such that [whatever] and so it must be true for all of them.

Comment: What's to prove? If $f \colon A\to B$ is a bijection **onto B** then $f^{-1}\colon B \to A$ is a bijection too hence a surjection.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to speak with my professor lol

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $a=f^{-1}(f(a)); a \in A$. Since $f^{-1}$ exists. Note that an injection is enough, using the same argument, only working on {$f(A)$} instead.

Comment: So using an argument that states since the number of elements in the domain of a bijective function is equal to the number of elements in the range of the bijective function and since the inverse exists since f is injective, we know that $\forall a\in A$ there exists $b\in B$ such that $a=f^{-1}(b)$?

Comment: Yes,  but maybe a good idea to generalize "number" to cardinality, for infinite sets.  You can also say: let $b=f(a)$. Then $f$ is invertible, with inverse function $f^{-1}$. Applying to both sides, we get : $f^{-1}f(a)=f^{-1}f(b))$ so that $a=f^{-1}(b)$, as you said.